# Code inspection highlight: cannot set different highlight style for Info and Weak Warning severities

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.1

In Android Studio 2.1.2 I'm having trouble setting the highlight style for the **Info** severity level (as determined by my code inspections profile). It shows up using the **Weak Warning** style instead.

I followed the instructions [from the official docs here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-inspection-severities.html#d1784066e91) but I don't see an entry for Info, only for Weak Warning. It feels like a bug in the IDE because when I click on the "Edit|Colors & Fonts" button, I'm taken to the last item I had selected in that section rather than to the correct item, ie "Info" (or perhaps that's because no such "Info" item exists).

I haven't been able to figure out how to add a new item for "Info" to the list under Colors & Fonts either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The INFO severity is deprecated as stated in a comment to the issue [IDEA-137974 Cannot change the color of the "info" severity](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137974):

> "INFO" level is deprecated since 2011 but it seems users don't know
>   about it. I removed this severity from settings (will be available in
>   2016.3). If you want to have an additional severity you can always create it.
>
> BTW in 2016.3 you will have INFORMATION severity. Particularly, this
>   severity has no highlighting.

So you can create your own severity with your favorite colors via `Severity -> Edit severities...` and use this one instead.

[image: Edit severities dialog]

Comment: the issue with creating my own severity is that there are about, oh a gazillion rules, that use info by default, so i need to update all of them.  i did know about the ability to create my own, i just wanted to avoid a mass-change... at any rate, thanks for digging around and finding all this info, you definitely did more than i was able to so you deserve the bounty. i'll award it shortly